# Safari bolding a light @font-face font on hover

Tags: css, fonts, safari, webkit, font-face

For some reason Safari is bolding my light @font-face font during transitions.

When you hover over the product images, you can see safari adding boldness to the text after a split second:

http://fine-grain-2.myshopify.com

Here are my @font-face declarations:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Avenir;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url("AvenirLTStd-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: AvenirBold;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
src: url("AvenirLTStd-Black.otf") format("opentype");
}

@font-face {
font-family: AvenirLight;
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
src: url("AvenirLTStd-Light.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Here is where I declare the font-family in the main CSS:

```
body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999999;
    font-family: AvenirLight;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Comment: The page is rather complicated. Try to reduce the problem to a simple test case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would imagine your problem is WebKit's antialiasing. Specifically, during transitions or transformations, the antialiasing is **whole-pixel only**, but when there are no transitions or transformations on the element LCD displays will by default use **subpixel** antialiasing.

Subpixel antialiasing is usually what you want, as it aids readability, but when something that's been involved in a transition stops, and the subpixel antialiasing takes over, the difference is jarring.

use `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` on the problem element **only** to force whole-pixel antialiasing all the time, and you'll lose that transition. See [this page](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2012/11/05/stop-fixing-font-smoothing/) for a great explanation of antialiasing vis-a-vis Safari.

Comment: wow you're the man!! Thanks! Anything you can do like this for firefox??

Comment: I don't think FF offers any antialiasing control via CSS. On the other hand, I've not noticed this problem occurring in FF. Which is odd, because to my eyes usually Safari has the more aesthetically pleasing rendering.

Comment: It's happening in FF for Mac and its quite an annoying problem. I might just let it slide for now and see if it corrects itself in a future release. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, you're referring to the heaviness of the type, rather than the jarring transition (which _doesn't_ happen for me in FF)? Yeah, I think you're stuffed on that one, I don't believe you can change it in FF.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I could spot there is that at:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: AvenirLight;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("AvenirLTStd-Light.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

lighter is not a valid value for the font-weight property. Valid values in this case would be: normal | bold | 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900

More details [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-webfonts/#font-descriptions) in section 4.4

Comment: Read the specs W3 link over there or try to validate.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong section. I told you to look under section 4.4 You are interested on embedding fonts, not the actual property. The following part is added from the document above doc itself: Relative keywords are not allowed, ‘bolder’ and ‘lighter’. Plus here's the validation screenshot: [link](http://i.imgur.com/6WiQxcu.png?1)

Comment: No problem. I'm curious if this was the issue with the webpage, after all.

Comment: Made the changes you suggested, but still bolding in safari for some reason.

Comment: On another idea, I see you are using antialiased fonts. Then try use: -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); on your class overlay, or on the actual h2 over there. By the way, I ran a couple of tests from here and i think it has nothing to do with how you load the fonts. It is an issue about font rendering. Does it still happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`, because font-weights will be inconsistent on different browsers.

I found out that the problem only occurred with a transition for the opacity property. In some cases a rgba background could do the trick.